# What are the exact problems with Octave's power operator?

Tags: math, octave

From [Octave docs about arithmetic operators § `x ** y` (power operator)](https://octave.org/doc/v4.4.1/Arithmetic-Ops.html):

> The implementation of this operator needs to be improved.

Ouch. So basically the documentation says "Please be careful, there are problems with this operator" but falls short of specifying what exact problems are to be expected.

What exactly must a user be aware of when using the `**` operator in Octave?

Comment: The note has been on the manual since [1996](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/b1a56412c385#l13.1037) and it may no longer be true. The way I read it it means that it's not as efficient as it could be and not that it's incorrect.

Comment: In particular if you compare the octave manual with the matlab one for the same function (i.e. [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html)), you will see that octave effectively states they will use the same 'approach' for implementing this operator as in matlab. My understanding of that disclaimer is that the devs may have felt that this strategy may not be the most efficient one (in that there are other methods in the literature that may be preferable), but for whatever reason they went with the matlab approach anyway.